# What does sf_frame_dur indicate in Android Logcat logs?

Tags: android, performance

In Logcat event logs, often have seen a print coming like this -

"**sf_frame_dur: [SurfaceView,29392,3147,42,8,5,0,4]**"

What does the numbers inside the bracket mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It means SurfaceView shows for a while. I think this is a surfaceflinger output log.

Some introduction in this file:

```
frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/EventLog/EventLogTags.logtags<br>
sf_frame_dur (window|3),(dur0|1),(dur1|1),(dur2|1),(dur3|1),(dur4|1),(dur5|1),(dur6|1)
```